# ERROR 3680 (HY000): Failed to create schema directory 'test' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, permissions, homebrew

I added mysql with homebrew. I try create a table using

`$ mysql -uroot`

then

`mysql> create database test;`

I get

`ERROR 3680 (HY000): Failed to create schema directory 'test' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)`

Edit

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Why are we seeing underscore before the mysql user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the permissions in your MySQL data directory are wrong.

Look into your data directory and make sure, that it is owned by the use MySQL is running as.

Comment: where is it on osx?

Comment: That depends on where you put it!

Comment: I just chmod 777 recursively and it worked. Probably not the best practice but it is only a local DB.

Comment: Definitly not best practice, but it confirms it was that permission problem.

Answer (score 1):

If SELinux is running, then it could be blocking the connection and it will produce the same type of error code.

Check the /var/log/messages file after the database creation fails.  If this is the case then you will need to create a policy in SELinux to allow the connection.